# Google Protobuf format error: input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am parsing a [GftsRealtime](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/) feed using [google protobuf parser](https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings/tree/master/java). Here is the exact error I am encountering: 
`com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.`
First thought that comes to mind is that the integrity of the file was compromised while downloading but I check the file in the Android emulator against the one I download on the desktop and it's the same. Has anyone encountered this issue before? I am using version '[0.0.4'](https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings/blob/master/java/README.md) of the gfts-realtime-parser. The feed is [here](http://developer.mbta.com/lib/GTRTFS/Alerts/TripUpdates.pb).

EDIT ----

Here is the code I use to download the file:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg urls: URL): Boolean? {
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient()
        val call = httpClient.newCall(Request.Builder().url(urls[0]).get().build())
        val urlStr = urls[0].toString()
        val fileName = urlStr.substring(urlStr.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, urlStr.length)
        val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName)
        try {
            val response = call.execute()
            if (response.code() === 200) {
                var inputStream: InputStream? = null
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                try {
                    inputStream = response.body().byteStream()
                    val buff = ByteArray(1024 * 4)
                    var downloaded: Long = 0
                    val target = response.body().contentLength()
                    publishProgress(0L, target)
                    while (true) {
                        val readed = inputStream!!.read(buff)
                        if (readed == -1) {
                            break
                        }
                        outputStream.write(buff, 0, readed)
                        //write buff
                        downloaded += readed.toLong()
                        publishProgress(downloaded, target)
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            fileListener(null)
                            return false
                        }
                    }
                    fileListener(file)
                    return downloaded == target
                } catch (ignore: IOException) {
                    fileListener(null)
                    return false
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream!!.close()
                    }
                    outputStream.flush()
                    outputStream.close()
                }
            } else {
                fileListener(null)
                return false
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            fileListener(null)
            return false
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2 ---- 
Here is the complete code path

```
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        Realm.init(applicationContext)
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build() // TODO remove before deploy
        RealmInstace = Realm.getInstance(config)

        Timber.i("Realm file path: ", RealmInstace?.path)
        val action = intent?.action
        when (action) {
            ACTION_UPDATE_GFTS -> updateGfts()
            ACTION_UPDATE_GFTS_REALTIME -> updateGftsReal() // this is called
            REALM_GET_ALL_TRAIN_MAP -> getTrainMapData(intent)
        }
        exportDatabase()
//        RealmInstace?.close()
        RealmInstace = null
    }

private fun updateGftsReal() {
        var file:File?=null
        AsyncDownloader(this, null, { f ->
            file = f
            if(file!=null && file!!.exists())
                GftsRealRealmParser(applicationContext, file!!, RealmInstace!!)
            else
                Timber.e("Failed to download trip updates", GFTS_REALTIME_TRIP_URL)
        }).execute(URL(GFTS_REALTIME_TRIP_URL)).get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    }

class GftsRealRealmParser(val context: Context, val file: File, val realm: Realm) {
    init {
        var feedr: FeedMessageR? = null
        var inputStream = BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(file))
        try {
            val url = URL("http://developer.mbta.com/lib/GTRTFS/Alerts/TripUpdates.pb")
            val feed = GtfsRealtime.FeedMessage.parseDelimitedFrom(url.openStream())
            feedr = FeedMessageR(feed)
            realm.executeTransaction {
                Timber.i("Committing ${feedr!!.entityList.size} to the realtime db.")
                realm?.copyToRealm(feedr)
//                val train = realm.where(TripDescriptorR::class.java).contains("route_id", "31760754").findFirst()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Timber.e(e.message, e)
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e.message, e)
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        if (feedr == null)
            throw ParseException("Failed to parse file", 0)
    }
}
```

EDIT 4 ----

see answer below

Comment: The error indicates that the data is corrupt. However, the file (which downloads as 227332 bytes for me) appears to be a valid protobuf -- the `protoc` tool decodes it just fine. Can you show your code? Maybe it has a bug.

Comment: Can you also show your protobuf deserialization code? Download code looks ok.

Comment: If you found the solution, do not edit your question, add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution. I was calling the wrong funtion. I was calling `parseDelimitedFrom` where I should've been calling `parseFrom`.